# Python How to repeat a list's elements in another list content until the length of the second list fulfilled?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, repeat

How to repeat a list's elements in another list content until the length of the second list fulfilled?
For example:

```
LA = [0,1,2]
LB = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0)]
the end result should be:
LC = [(0,0,0),(1,0,1),(2,0,2),(3,0,0),(4,0,1),(5,0,2),(6,0,0)]
```

Hopefully it can be done in one line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

LA = [0,1,2]
LB = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0)]

LC = [(i, j, k) for (i, j), k in zip(LB, cycle(LA))]
print LC
# [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 1), (5, 0, 2), (6, 0, 0)]
```

This works because `zip` generates items until one of the iterables is exhausted...but a [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) object is **inexhaustible**, so we'll keep padding items from `LA` until `LB` runs out.

Comment: [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) since you beat me to it :)

Comment: This worked, Thank you Moses for the extra explanation I needed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `enumerate()` like this along with list comprehension -

```
[elem + (LA[i % len(LA)],) for i, elem in enumerate(LB)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#use list comprehension and get the element from LA by using the index from LB %3.
[v+(LA[k%3],) for k,v in enumerate(LB)]
Out[718]: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 1], [5, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a more "explicit" version that works with any length of LA.

```
LA = [0,1,2]
LB = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0)]

i = 0
LC = []
for x,y in LB:
    try:
        z = LA[i]
    except IndexError:
        i = 0
        z = LA[i]
    LC.append((x,y,z))
    i += 1

print LC
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (3, 0, 0), (4, 0, 1), (5, 0, 2), (6, 0, 0)]
```